# Add a common module for methods to be used by my client / server in Maven

Tags: maven

I wanted to create a "Common" module in order to store my common methods in it for my Client and Server to use. To do so I simply created the module, and added the following to my sub-modules `pom`s:

```
 <dependency>
         <groupId>com.christopher.kade</groupId>
         <artifactId>common</artifactId>
         <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
 </dependency>
```

Additionally, I don't want my `common` module to generate a `.jar` file, I just want my other modules to access its content, so here is its `pom`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>jcoinche</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.christopher.kade</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>common</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>common</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

What should I change in order to make this build work? So far it builds 3 `.jar`s and I can't access my common methods in my client or server module.

Comment: What's wrong with `common.jar`? Why you don't want to generate it?

Comment: Do *client* and *server* have *common* as dependency?

Comment: I am required to only generate `.jar`s for my client and my server, is there any way I can compile my common methods in both of these?

Comment: I don't think so, you're defeating the purpose of dependencies; moreover, a jar is a collections of classes (plus some other feats), so I don't see your point; anyway, others could have better suggestions.